# Equality on Riemann and Lebesgue integral (basic question)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R_+}$ two real functions so that $\int f(u)g(u)du$ exists. Does 
$$\int f(u)g(u)du=\int fgd\mu \quad ?$$
where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure (if not, what conditions should be imposed to make it true?). Secondly, if I suppose $g$ with compact support, say $supp \ g=[-a,a]$, then
$$\int f(u)g(u)du=\int_{-a}^a f(u)g(u)du=\int_{[-a,a]} fgd\mu \quad ?$$

Can you help me to clarify these points?

This question came from a book I'm reading. The author presented a Riemann integral and then stated results about $\mu$-almost everywhere related to that Riemann integral. So, it is clear that he treated the Riemann integral as Lebesgue integral. I just want to make the equivalence clear. It is important to mention that, in the case, $g$ is symmetric, bounded, nonnegative, has compact support, and $f$ is a polynomial.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Addition to Kabo's answer.  In the example $\int\sin(x)/x\;dx$ change variables to get the example
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\sin(1/x)}{x} dx
$$
where the improper Riemann integral exists, but the Lebesgue integral does not.  The problem is that the OP does not say his functions are continuous.

---

As noted in a comment from Celine Harumi: if a **nonnegative** function is improperly Riemann integrable, then it is Lebesgue integrable.  So this is what the OP needs.

Comment: In addition, this function is not nonnegative.

Comment: Right... I should add that.

Answer (score 0):

Any Riemann  integrable function on $[a,b]$ is Lebesgue integrable and the two integrals are the same . However we cannot say the  same about improper Riemann  integrals. A well known example is $\frac {\sin x} x$ on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: As far as I understand, if $g$ has compact support, then it is correct to write $\int f(u)g(u)du=\int fgd\mu$, right?